# Calling functions from within functions JS

Tags: javascript, object

I'm writing a small battleships game, and I'm refactoring my code using Javascript Objects, a tool that I am not very familiar with. I would like to be able to call a function from within a function using objects, and I cannot seem to work out how to do this. The code is here:

```
<script>
var xPos;
var yPos;
var boatGrid = {

    selectPos : function() {
        console.log("it works"); //want to try calling function addNumber() here
        for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        }
    },
    buildBoat : function() {
        console.log("this works too");
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            xPos = xPos++;
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
        }
    },
    addNumber : function() {
        document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = "hello"; //debug line
    }
}
```

The addNum() function is there as a debug.

Comment: I can't get it. Did you mean calling a `boatGrid.addNumber()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

In your case `boatGrid` is an object and `addNumber` is one of it's method. so use `this.addNumber()`

```
var xPos;
var yPos;
var boatGrid = {

    selectPos : function() {
        console.log("it works"); //want to try calling function addNumber() here
     this.addNumber();   // Changed here
     for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        }
    },
    buildBoat : function() {
        console.log("this works too");
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            xPos = xPos++;
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
        }
    },
    addNumber : function() {
        //document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = "hello"; //debug line
   document.write('<pre>Add Number called</pre>')

    }
}
boatGrid.selectPos();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rjkwhqL/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `boatGrid.selectPos()` and call the `addNumber` function within the `selectPos` function, just add `this.addNumber();` within the `selectPos` function.

```
    selectPos : function() {
        console.log("it works");
        this.addNumber(); // <---- boatGrid calls addNumber()
        for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        }
    }
```

When used within an object function, `this` refers to the object calling the function.

So to go with my original example, `boatGrid` calls `selectPos`, so `this` within the `selectPos` function refers to `boatGrid`.

So then `this.addNumber()` will have that `boatGrid` object call its `addNumber` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
this.addNumber();
```

Your code should look like this

```
selectPos : function() {
    console.log("it works");
    this.addNumber(); //want to try calling function addNumber() here
    for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
        xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
        yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    }
},
```